# Chrome on Windows triggers d3.zoom behavior on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I'm creating an interactive map using dc.js and d3.js. The map should support zooming and panning, so I'm using the d3.zoom behavior. I also want a function to run when I click areas on the map. The code works as expected in Firefox (Linux and Windows), IE, and Chrome (Linux), but Chrome version 47 on Windows interprets the clicks as attempts to zoom, which suppresses the click events. Is there any way to avoid this?

I created a simplified [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjmorris/gaysnspy/) to demonstrate the issue. The code is below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var container = d3.select('#container');
var fmt = d3.format('.2f');

var svg = container.append('svg')
    .attr('width', 400)
    .attr('height', 400)
    .append('g');

var colors = ['#444488', '#448844', '#884444'];

svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(colors)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return 50 + 100*i; })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i) { return 50 + 100*i; })
    .attr('r', function(d, i) { return 10 + 10*i; })
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d; })
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
        // Skip the click handler if preventDefault was called. This prevents the click
        // handler from running at the end of a drag.
        if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
            console.log('clicked circle #' + i);
        }
    });

var zoomBehavior = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 15])
    .translate([0, 0])
    .on('zoom', function() {
        console.log('got zoom: scale = ' + fmt(d3.event.scale) + ', translate = [' + fmt(d3.event.translate[0]) + ',' + fmt(d3.event.translate[1]) + ']');
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    });

container.call(zoomBehavior);
```

The demo adds three circles to the SVG and gives each one a click handler. It also adds the d3.zoom behavior to the container element. I want it to do the following:

- Clicking a circle runs the cirlce's click handler.
- Using the mousewheel zooms in and out, whether the mouse is over a circle or the background.
- Clicking and dragging pans the area, whether the click/drag starts over a circle or over the background. If it starts over a circle, the circle's click handler shouldn't be run.

All these requirements are met by the demo in Firefox and IE. In Chrome, when I click a circle, the zoom handler runs instead of the click handler. Does anyone have suggestions for how to deal with this?

As another approach, I tried putting a rectangle either above or below the rest of the SVG elements and attaching the zoom behavior to the rectangle instead of the container, but I ran into various issues with events not reaching the correct element. I'm willing to explore that further if people think that's the way to go.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue with the jsfiddle you provided. In Chrome, it only zooms on double click.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: Was this Chrome on Windows?

Comment: I just checked on Chrome in Linux, and it works as expected there. (It runs the click handler when I click a circle.) I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: Changed again, it works on Windows.

Comment: Maybe you're slightly dragging it when you click sometimes?

Comment: No, I don't think I was slightly dragging when clicking. For one thing, I tried it many times in Chrome and Firefox, and it always worked in Firefox and never worked in Chrome. If my hand were unsteady, it should be equally so in both. Also, I printed the value of d3.event.translate, and it was the same for successive clicks, meaning I wasn't moving the mouse.

Comment: Well I can't seem to replicate it, hopefully someone else can be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with an old version of d3 (3.3.3). I'm not sure if it's been fixed since. The problem, as you said, is that Chrome gets in a weird state where a mouse click triggers a mousemove event. Completely closing Chrome and reopening it seems to get it out of this state.

I was able to resolve the issue by checking in d3's mousemove function for actual movement. I added two lines to the moved() function within mousedowned() in d3:

```
function moved() {
    if(d3.event.movementX === 0 && d3.event.movementY === 0) // new
        return false; // new
    dragged = 1;
    translateTo(d3.mouse(target), l);
    zoomed(event_);
}
```

That seems to resolve the problem without having to restart Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

My Chrome instance must have gotten into some strange state while I was developing and debugging. I restarted Chrome and tried again, and now it's working fine.